# Python and SQL - most efficient way to check if Row exists - if not INSERT it

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, insert

I would like to check what is the most efficient Python method (because of the performances) how to check if some row exists in SQL, and if not, then insert it.
I want to check if for some value, row exists in table and if not insert it.
I did it like this , but I was wondering if there is some better way.

```
  insertValue="test"        
  mycursor.execute("SELECT * from CUSTOMERS where name ="+'insertValue')
  myresult2 = mycursor.fetchall()
  if not myresult2:
    print 'Row does not EXIST'
    mycusrsor.execute(.....INSERT part for insertValue in table TABLE_2.....)
```

Is this this optimal method for Python execution (code optimization), or this can be done in more efficient way (from the perspective of Python code optimization)
Thanks

Comment: First optimization would be to not use `SELECT *` instead, do `SELECT <primary key>`

Comment: Secondly, add index on the `name` column.

Comment: I was thinking more from the Python perspective, code optimization for execution - not SQL. Sorry for misunderstanding. I clarified in more details this now

Answer (score -1):

From the tags used it seems you are using "MYSQL". It provides an option as "INSERT IGNORE" which means that if the key is already present, it will not throw an execution error and will move on to the next row.

This will prove to be the most efficient way and with very less code.

Comment: It will work only when either `name` is PK or `name` is set to UNIQUE

Comment: Name is not PK and also it is not set to UNIQUE

Comment: Do mention such constraints before hand itself